# Jira 6: How to assign issue by condition

Tags: workflow, jira

I creating new workflow and I need to assign issues by condition.

For example:

During create issue if in the dropdown list I select "language_1" issue will be assigned to "translator_1" or if I select "langiage_2", issue will be assigned to "translator_2"

I tried to do this in workflow editor by creating post function, but this functions can't verify conditions. Does Jira have any other method to do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you share the work you've done so far?  That would help us better help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use JIRA components to do this. Create a component named "language_1" with a component lead of your first user. When the issue is created set the component and leave the Assignee at automatic.

Comment: And if that doesn't work then create a custom post function in Java or using the Script Runner add-on

Answer (score 0):

I used the [Script runner plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) to do something similar by adding a post function to the required transaction. Code example:

from com.atlassian.jira import ComponentManager

```
customFieldManager = ComponentManager.getInstance().getCustomFieldManager()
userUtil = ComponentManager.getInstance().getUserUtil()

# read field
language = issue.getCustomFieldValue(customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Language"))

if (language == "language_1") {
    issue.setAssignee(userUtil.getUserObject("translator_1"))
} else if (language == "language_2") {
    issue.setAssignee(userUtil.getUserObject("translator_2"))
}
```